# Validating Contact Us Form using Javascript, Drop Down Menu not returning false

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I've been working on this assignment all day and can't seem to see where I'm going wrong. Watched some YouTube videos and googled for days, following closely, but still missing something.

I'm supposed to use Javascript to validate a Contact Us form. Here are the instructions:

1. "Name" and either "Phone Number" or "Email" must be filled out or an an alert pops up (I have this working so far)
2. If "Other" is selected from the drop down menu, user must fill out "Additional Info" text area, or an alert will show
3. User must check at least one of the days to be contacted by, or an alert

```js
function checkForm() {
  var name = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("emailInput").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("phoneInput").value;
  var inquirySelect = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
  var addInfoBox = document.getElementById("textInput").value;

  if (name == "") {
    alert("Name is required");
    return false;
  } else if (email == "" && phone == "") {
    alert("Please provide your email address or a phone number");
    return false;
  } else if (inquirySelect == "Other" && addInfoBox == "") {
    alert("Please add additional info");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="contactForm" action="submission.html" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
  <table id="form">
    <tr>
      <td id="question">Name:</td>
      <td id="answer">
        <input type="text" name="Name" id="nameInput">
      </td>
      <td id="question"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="question">Email:</td>
      <td id="answer">
        <input type="text" name="Email" id="emailInput">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="question">Phone:</td>
      <td id="answer">
        <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneInput">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="question">Reason for Inquiry:</td>
      <td id="answer">
        <select name="reason" id="dropdown">
          <option value="Catering">Catering</option>
          <option value="Private Party">Private Party</option>
          <option value="Feedback">Feedback</option>
          <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="question">Additional Information:</td>
      <td id="answer">
        <textarea name="additionalInfo" id="textInput">
        </textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="question">Have you been to the restaurant?:</td>
      <td id="answer">
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="NO" checked>No
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="YES">Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="question">Best days to contact you:</td>
      <td id="answer">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1">M
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="2">T
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="3">W
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="4">Th
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="5">F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td id="answer">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Request">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

So far I am able to get Step 1 working. However I can't seem to get Step 2 to return false, it will always go through.

I haven't started working on the last step, but I know I'll be using a for loop to go through the checked values and return false if none are checked. Hopefully I won't have to be back on here for that one lol. I appreciate the help on this, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clear empty space between tag textarea :

your code is :

```
<textarea name="additionalInfo" id="textInput">
</textarea></td>
```

change like this :

```
<textarea name="additionalInfo" id="textInput"></textarea></td>
```

work for me.

Comment: Nice catch @ehsan. If there's a newline at the HTML the value is not null so that's why the alert didn't show up; `document.getElementById("textInput").value -->
"     "`

Comment: Oh the empty space before the closing tag. It works! Thanks you!

Comment: This has been driving me mad all day lol I really appreciate it!